# Fragment not attached to the FragmentManager when loading Admob

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, admob

Getting the following error when trying to load my [NativeAd](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/native/start) -

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: onGetLayoutInflater() cannot be executed until the Fragment is attached to the FragmentManager.
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.getLayoutInflater(Fragment.java:1435)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.onGetLayoutInflater(Fragment.java:1384)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performGetLayoutInflater(Fragment.java:1416)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.getLayoutInflater(Fragment.java:1401)
    at app.meeq.MapFragment$loadAd$1.onUnifiedNativeAdLoaded(MapFragment.kt:683)
```

**MapFragment.kt**

```
class MapFragment : Fragment() {


private fun loadAd() {
    val builder = AdLoader.Builder(context, getString(R.string.test_admob_app_unit_id))
    builder.forUnifiedNativeAd { unifiedNativeAd ->
        /** Populate UnifiedNativeAdView with loaded NativeAd */
        val adView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.ad_unified, null) as UnifiedNativeAdView
        populateUnifiedNativeAdView(unifiedNativeAd, adView)
    }
    /** Load ad */
    val adLoader = builder
        .withAdListener(object : AdListener() {
            override fun onAdFailedToLoad(errorCode: Int) {
                log("Ad failed to load: $errorCode")
            }
        }).build()
    adLoader.loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())
}
```

**ad_unified.xml**

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.formats.UnifiedNativeAdView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ad_unified">
    <TextView style="@style/AdAttribution"/>
    <include
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        layout="@layout/fragment_profile">
    </include>
</com.google.android.gms.ads.formats.UnifiedNativeAdView>
```

when it says `onGetLayoutInflater() cannot be executed until the Fragment is attached to the FragmentManager` - what Fragment is it referring to? `loadAd()` is called in `onStart()` of the fragment so `MapFragment` is definitely attached to the Fragment Manager.

How can I work around this problem?

Comment: did you found a solution? I have the same question.

Answer (score 0):

You have not created the fragments view. Add these two override methods:

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false)
}
```

then call the function loadad() method in here :

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    loadAd()
}
```

Comment: I have already overriden `onCreateView()`, like you have shown above to create the fragment view. `loadAd()` is called in `onResume()` which is after `onCreateView()` so there shouldn't be a problem - but there is.

Answer (score 0):

A little too late but if using a fragment, its best if you load the Ads inside `onStart` & not in `onCreateView`. Additionaly, [isAdded](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment#isAdded()) method will tell you whether or not the fragment is added to the activity.

This is how to solve the issue:

```
@Override
public void onStart(){
    if(isAdded()){
        //Load your Ad
    }
}
```